# console Output in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python3 in VS CODE.

I'm trying to print the console output into my Tkinter WIDGET (textbox)

this is my code:

```
def TraceRoute():
target = traceInput.get()
hops = tracehops.get()
if hops == "":
    hops = str(10)
r = os.system("tracert " + "-h "+ hops + " " + target)
textMenu2.insert("end-1c", r, "Data")
```

I expect the CMD output which is this:

Tracing route to twitter.com `[104.244.42.1]`  (twitter it's just a test)
over a maximum of 3 hops:

```
  1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.176.228.2
  2     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  10.176.232.5
  3     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  10.176.232.2
```

Trace complete.
0

but my console it's only showing "0"

how can i achieve this?

Comment: `os.system` is documented to return the return code of the process, not the output.

Comment: is there a way to return the process?

Answer (score 0):

Well,nvm i solved it like this.

```
def TraceRoute():
target = traceInput.get()
hops = tracehops.get()
if hops == "":
    hops = str(10)
a = os.popen("tracert " + "-h " + hops + " " + target).readlines()
textMenu2.insert("end-1c", a, "Data")
```